# getAttribute Returns [object Window] Instead of Value

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug

I am writing out a hierarchical set of elements to the DOM document using JavaScript and am debugging using FireBug on FireFox 20.0.  Based upon what I see when examining the DOM using FireBug, it seems that the writing out is going fine.  The part of interest has the following structure.

```
childNodes NodeList[ulcorner, lrcorner]
- 0 ulcorner    
    accessKey  ""
    accessKeyLabel""
    - attributes    [xcoord="134", ycoord="49"]
    + 0 xcoord="134"
    + 1 ycoord="49"
```

However, when I call

```
var ulCorner=upperElement.getElementsByTagName("ulCorner")[0];
top=ulCorner.getAttribute("yCoord");
left=ulCorner.getAttribute("xCoord");
console.log('top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

I get

```
top=[object Window], left=134
```

Why is top set to [object Window] instead of 49?

Comment: What is an elemant? Maybe `<elephant />`:-)

Comment: I am generating the DOM tree programatically.  There is no XML file involved.  AFAIK there is no way to output the tree structure to a file using JavaScript since it is a client side language.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Oh, why do you use XML then instead of plain JS objects? However, you can stringify a DOM to XML by using a `XMLSerializer`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into that.  I would like to be able to output my DOM documents to XML files but thought that I needed to use PHP, or maybe Java, for that.  I did not think I could do it with JavaScript.  Thanks again, Peter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`top` is an existing property on the `window` object and it's **non-writable** https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.top

```
var ulCorner=upperElement.getElementsByTagName("ulCorner")[0];
var top=ulCorner.getAttribute("yCoord");
var left=ulCorner.getAttribute("xCoord");
console.log('top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

The above should work, however it's not recommended to shadow existing global variables and I strongly advise you to select another variable name, unless your code doesn't run in the global scope.

Comment: That was my problem.  I changed the variable to a different name and that fixed the problem.  I found that putting var before top, to make the variable local, also fixed the problem.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> top=ulCorner.getAttribute("yCoord");
> ```

You are creating an implicitly (and accidently) global variable here, i.e a property of the global object. The global object is `window` in browsers, and [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top) is a **non-writable** "*reference to the topmost window in the window hierarchy*". So your assignment has no effect, and it just returns the top `window` (whose stringification is `"[object Window]"`).

To fix this, just add the [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

```
var ulCorner=upperElement.getElementsByTagName("ulCorner")[0];
var top=ulCorner.getAttribute("yCoord");
var left=ulCorner.getAttribute("xCoord");
```

or use a multiple var-statement:

```
var ulCorner=upperElement.getElementsByTagName("ulCorner")[0],
    top=ulCorner.getAttribute("yCoord"),
    left=ulCorner.getAttribute("xCoord");
```

Comment: Yes indeed!  That was the problem.  I forgot to make the variable local by prepending var or using a non-reserved variable name. Thanks very much!